# Programmatically create asp:Button and attach event in SharePoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm trying to create ASP.NET buttons programmatically inside an update panel in my SharePoint instance, but because of the page life cycle, I can not attach server side events on buttons.

Here is the code:

```
TableCell tcellbutton = new TableCell();
b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
b.CausesValidation = true;
tcellbutton.Controls.Add(b);
tr.Cells.Add(tcellbutton);
table.Rows.Add(tr);
panel1.Controls.Add(table);

void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string studentnumber = (sender as Button).ID.ToString().Substring(3, (sender as Button).ID.ToString().Length - 3);
    TextBox t = panel1.FindControl("txt" + studentNumber) as TextBox;
}
```

Is there another way to create and attach buttons in Sharepoint?

Comment: Fix your formatting and put in a full code snippet (what method or event are you adding the controls in, for example - this is almost certainly the problem and you've left it out) and it might get you a little more help.

Comment: Hi Ryan, My problem here is basically I can not attach events to controls during runtime, It has to be during the Page Initialization, I can override and run the same code without any error but my question is if it is available in the runtime as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is how I solved it, Thanks for all replies, I was looking for a way to attach an event to a button that is created dynamically during runtime (after initialization). Hope It works for others as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ButtonClick(buttonId) {
        alert("Button " + buttonId + " clicked from javascript");
    }
</script> 

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), ((Button)sender).ID, "<script>alert('Button_Click');</script>");
    Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + ((Button)sender).ID + " was clicked");
}    

private Button GetButton(string id, string name)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Text = name;
    b.ID = id;
    b.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
    b.OnClientClick = "ButtonClick('" + b.ClientID + "')";
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer as correct (by pressing on a tick)

Answer (score 1):

You should add your code in `PreInit` event, code below work good:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
    Button bb = new Button();
    bb.Click += new EventHandler(bb_Click);
    bb.CausesValidation = true;
    bb.ID = "button1";
    Panel1.Controls.Add(bb);
}

private void bb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("any thing here");
}
```

Comment: is it possible to call OnPreInit() in another Event ?

Comment: You don't call OnPreInit - the web part infrastructure calls it on your behalf. http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2009/02/14/understanding-web-part-life-cycle/

Comment: you just override OnPreInit, not call it.

Comment: @Kubi I think you can't, try below solution of @Kubi

Answer (score 1):

You are creating dynamic controls. Your code should execute in each `PageLoad` event.
Remove `IsPostBack` for the part of code where you are creating the buttons is my advice.

If you don't do this, you will create the controls, but each time when `PageLoad` event occurs, your control will be deleted and the application will not follow your events. With other words you should always recreate the controls.